# Allowing foreign characters

Tags: php, regex

I have this PHP regex code:

```
$input = $_POST['name_field'];

if (!preg_match("/^[\pL0-9_.,!\"' ]+$/", $input)) {
    echo 'error';
}
```

However, if `$input` contains characters like `á`, `é`, etcetera, it indicates an error (i.e. echoes `error`).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add the u modifier. and it is more efficient to negate the character class: `if (preg_match("/[^\pL0-9_.,!\"' ]/u", $input))`

Comment: You should add that as an answer so I can mark this as solved. :)

Comment: I immediately had the same comment – as far as the `u` pattern modifier: so I went ahead and added it as an answer accordingly.

Comment: Check your definition of "foreign".  PHP was written by somebody originally from Greenland.

Answer (score 0):

As Casimir et Hippolyte commented and [PHP documentation confirms](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), you need to employ the `u` pattern modifier to support UTF-8 characters:

> This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is
>   incompatible with Perl. Pattern and subject strings are treated as
>   UTF-8.

An adaptation of your code demonstrates that the `u` pattern modifier works as you want:

```
<?php

// NOTE: array of sample input strings to demonstrate
$inputs = array(
    'my_fiancée',            // match expected
    'über',                  // match expected
    'my_bloody_valentine',   // match expected
    '"ABC, Easy as 123!"',   // match expected
    'whocares@whocares.com', // match NOT expected
    "'foo'",                 // match expected
    'bar?');                 // match NOT expected

foreach($inputs as $input) {
    if (!preg_match("/^[\pL0-9_.,!\"' ]+$/u", $input)) {
        //                                ^
        echo "\"$input\" => error\r\n"; // FORNOW: to explicitly note non-matches
        //echo 'error';
    } else { // FORNOW: else to explicitly indicate matches
        echo "\"$input\" => all good\r\n";
    }
}

?>
```

It outputs the following:

```
"my_fiancée" => all good
"über" => all good
"my_bloody_valentine" => all good
""ABC, Easy as 123!"" => all good
"whocares@whocares.com" => error
"'foo'" => all good
"bar?" => error
```

You can also [check the adaptation of your code through Ideone](http://ideone.com/stCJl4).